# Restarting the windows service leads to multiple process instance

Tags: windows, service, windows-service

I have one background monitoring windows service which runs 24x7. I observed sometime when i do restart of service using windows service controller then it shows two instances of processes running.  Sometime there are 4 to 6 instances of processes running if i do restart of windows service multiple times

This does not happen during boot time or when i do STOP and then START of service, but specifically when i do restart of service.

Comment: This will be caused by a bug or design flaw in the service itself.  Contact the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Use [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).
It is tool by Microsoft sysinternals to audit services, programs which are running automatically during the boot time. 
It grabs the registry to do this.

Comment: This does not happen during boot time, but specifically when i do restart of service. Not even, when i do STOP and then START of service.

Comment: There is a tool called [regshot](sourceforge.net/p/regshot/wiki/Home). Take the registry shots before and after restarting the service. Then compare both to check which registry it is tweaking. I assume some parent process is spawning into multiple processes.